# MySQL complex query - SUM over several databases using UNION ALL and internal JOINs

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sum

I want to calculate a SUM over several databases using UNION ALL and internal JOINs. The MySQL user has the permissions to access all databases relevant.

Here is my SQL query code so far:

```
SELECT
    SUM(summen.OP1OPVerfahren = "0") AS "Keine Operation durchgeführt",
    SUM(summen.OP1OPVerfahren = "1") AS "Bioenterics Intragastric Ballon (BIB)",
    SUM(summen.OP1OPVerfahren = "2") AS "Gastric Banding",
    SUM(summen.OP1OPVerfahren = "3") AS "Roux-en-Y Gastric Bypass",
    SUM(summen.OP1OPVerfahren LIKE "%") AS "Summe"

FROM
(
    SELECT
        SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "0") AS "Keine Operation durchgeführt",
        SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "1") AS "Bioenterics Intragastric Ballon (BIB)",
        SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "2") AS "Gastric Banding",
        SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "3") AS "Roux-en-Y Gastric Bypass",
        SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren LIKE "%") AS "Summe"
        FROM ods01.dat_patient p
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ods01.dat_optherapie op ON op.PatID = p.ID
        WHERE Testzwecke = 0
        AND p.ID = op.PatID  -- possibly redundant
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                        FROM ods01.dat_optherapie op2
                        WHERE op2.PatID = p.ID AND op2.revision > op.revision)
        GROUP BY OP1OPVerfahren

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "0") AS "Keine Operation durchgeführt",
        SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "1") AS "Bioenterics Intragastric Ballon (BIB)",
        SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "2") AS "Gastric Banding",
        SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "3") AS "Roux-en-Y Gastric Bypass",
        SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren LIKE "%") AS "Summe"
        FROM ods02.dat_patient p
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ods02.dat_optherapie op ON op.PatID = p.ID
        WHERE Testzwecke = 0
        AND p.ID = op.PatID  -- possibly redundant
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                        FROM ods02.dat_optherapie op2
                        WHERE op2.PatID = p.ID AND op2.revision > op.revision)
        GROUP BY OP1OPVerfahren
) summen

GROUP BY OP1OPVerfahren
```

Whatever I do in the first 5 lines - leave the "summen.", leave away the "summen." or exchange it with "op." - I receive an error message:

> SQL error (1054): Unknown column 'summen.OP1OPVerfahren' in 'field
>   list'

... or ...

> SQL error (1054): Unknown column 'OP1OPVerfahren' in 'field list'

... or ...

> SQL error (1054): Unknown column 'op.OP1OPVerfahren' in 'field list'

Where is my logic mistake?

I have seen all other references about this here, but did not find any topic conerning the integration of JOINed tables (which should not be the issue).

Has anyone got an idea what I need to change?

Comment: Replace the first 5 lines with `SELECT *`. Do you see the column `OP1OPVerfahren`? No? MySQL neither. And thus complains "Unknown column .."

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @Paul-Spiegel, good thinking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already  assign the alias so you can refer to the inner column name

```
SELECT
  SUM(summen.`Keine Operation durchgeführt`),
  SUM(summen.`Bioenterics Intragastric Ballon (BIB)`),
  SUM(summen.`Gastric Banding`),
  SUM(summen.`Roux-en-Y Gastric Bypass`),
  SUM(summen.`Summe`)

FROM
(
  SELECT
      SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "0") AS "Keine Operation durchgeführt",
      SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "1") AS "Bioenterics Intragastric Ballon (BIB)",
      SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "2") AS "Gastric Banding",
      SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "3") AS "Roux-en-Y Gastric Bypass",
      SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren LIKE "%") AS "Summe"
      FROM ods01.dat_patient p
      LEFT OUTER JOIN ods01.dat_optherapie op ON op.PatID = p.ID
      WHERE Testzwecke = 0
      AND p.ID = op.PatID  -- possibly redundant
      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM ods01.dat_optherapie op2
                      WHERE op2.PatID = p.ID AND op2.revision > op.revision)
      GROUP BY OP1OPVerfahren

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
      SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "0"),
      SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "1"),
      SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "2"),
      SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "3"),
      SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren LIKE "%")
      FROM ods02.dat_patient p
      LEFT OUTER JOIN ods02.dat_optherapie op ON op.PatID = p.ID
      WHERE Testzwecke = 0
      AND p.ID = op.PatID  -- possibly redundant
      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM ods02.dat_optherapie op2
                      WHERE op2.PatID = p.ID AND op2.revision > op.revision)
      GROUP BY OP1OPVerfahren
  ) summen
```

Comment: Thank you very much, @scaisEdge, this turned out to be the right solution.

Comment: @mtjmohr - But this makes no sense. If you don't need a GROUP BY in the outer query, you also don't need it in the subqueries. And it looks like there is more unnecessary and confusing code.

Comment: Unnecessary is "AND p.ID = op.PatID"; I have eliminated the GROUP BY statement in the outer and inner areas and that does not change the results. What do you think is confusing, @Paul-Spiegel?

Comment: @mtjmohr `AND p.ID = op.PatID` is converting the LEFT JOIN to INNER JOIN. But LEFT JOIN makes no sense here, since NULL entries (if present) would be ignored bei `SUM()`. That might make no difference. But it's confusing the reviewers, because they have to ask: "Why is it written that way?" `SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren LIKE "%")` is equivalent to `COUNT(op.OP1OPVerfahren)`. If `op.OP1OPVerfahren` cannot be NULL, it's equivalent to `COUNT(*)`. It's not clear which table `Testzwecke` belongs to. If it's not from `dat_patient`, then you probably don't need to query that table at all.

Comment: Thank you, @Paul-Spiegel. The INNER JOIN conversion was old code, I am sorry, I have done away with it. Any other joins but a LEFT OUTER JOIN do not deploy usable results; using this form of JOINing, even not logically correct, deploys the right number of results (SQL query vs. hand-counted). The SUM statement is not relevant here since I used it only as a quantitative check for the total number of surgeries. Testzwecke should be p.Testzwecke, correct, but it does not play a role here, either.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add OP1OPVerfahren in selection list for both inner queries-

```
SELECT
    SUM(OP1OPVerfahren = "0") AS "Keine Operation durchgeführt",
    SUM(OP1OPVerfahren = "1") AS "Bioenterics Intragastric Ballon (BIB)",
    SUM(OP1OPVerfahren = "2") AS "Gastric Banding",
    SUM(OP1OPVerfahren = "3") AS "Roux-en-Y Gastric Bypass",
    SUM(OP1OPVerfahren LIKE "%") AS "Summe"

FROM
(
    SELECT OP1OPVerfahren,
        SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "0") AS "Keine Operation durchgeführt",
        SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "1") AS "Bioenterics Intragastric Ballon (BIB)",
        SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "2") AS "Gastric Banding",
        SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "3") AS "Roux-en-Y Gastric Bypass",
        SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren LIKE "%") AS "Summe"
        FROM ods01.dat_patient p
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ods01.dat_optherapie op ON op.PatID = p.ID
        WHERE Testzwecke = 0
        AND p.ID = op.PatID  -- possibly redundant
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                        FROM ods01.dat_optherapie op2
                        WHERE op2.PatID = p.ID AND op2.revision > op.revision)
        GROUP BY OP1OPVerfahren

    UNION ALL

    SELECT OP1OPVerfahren,
        SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "0") AS "Keine Operation durchgeführt",
        SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "1") AS "Bioenterics Intragastric Ballon (BIB)",
        SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "2") AS "Gastric Banding",
        SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "3") AS "Roux-en-Y Gastric Bypass",
        SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren LIKE "%") AS "Summe"
        FROM ods02.dat_patient p
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ods02.dat_optherapie op ON op.PatID = p.ID
        WHERE Testzwecke = 0
        AND p.ID = op.PatID  -- possibly redundant
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                        FROM ods02.dat_optherapie op2
                        WHERE op2.PatID = p.ID AND op2.revision > op.revision)
        GROUP BY OP1OPVerfahren
) summen
GROUP BY OP1OPVerfahren
```

Comment: Thank you, @fa06, I understand the logic behind it, however, it did not lead to the right result.